# Should I install Any Drivers After ubuntu installation like sound driver , landriver

Tags: drivers

i am new to this  should i install any drivers in it so it can be functionally active
And what extension it uses for softwares

Comment: unless you mention us what hardware you got , we cant tell you.

Comment: possibly he is talking about Graphic Card but did not mentioned anything , so this question must be updated with actual computer specification ..

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will take care of few drivers. Among them sound drivers are default. Very rare case we see that here no sound issues but those problems are also got fixed very easily.

while coming to VGDA drivers , nvidia drivers are not provided by default. you have to install them manually. Ubuntu have application for searching your drivers also.

Now bigger issues I have seen in Ubuntu are Wi-Fi issues. Some drivers installed by default and some of them or not. Some manufactures were even not provide Linux support.

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried it yet?**

If not, try Ubuntu as a live disc - seems to me, chances are, if it works on the live disc, it should work on your PC. This is a risk-free way to try Linux without changing anything on your PC. How do you do a live disc? Simply download Ubuntu, burn it to a DVD and then boot from that DVD. If you don't know how to boot from a DVD, that's a separate question entirely, but you can ask.

**Does it work? Is it broken?**

If you tried Ubuntu, and everything seems to be working - you can connect to WiFi/internet, play your music CDs, etc. - great! Enjoy the freedom and security of Linux. You should really only need to worry if there is something specific that isn't working. If this is the case, come back and describe what you expected your PC to do, what you tried to get it working, and what happened when you tried it.

**Extensions for Software?**

Ubuntu (Linux), unlike Windows, doesn't need a special extension (ie: .EXE, .BAT, .MSI...) for executables - in other words, programs and software. For newbies (like me!) installing software in Ubuntu is really easy. Instructions on using the Software Center can be found here: [Install additional software on Ubuntu.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-install.html)

When using Linux, like most things, Google is your friend. Best of luck!